# Package installation error - Find corrupted items

Tags: azure, packages

I'm experiencing this problem when installing packages in an instance hosted on Azure.
The package installation fails and the dialog just says - Retry installation. There are also no related logs.
On investigation, it is found that some related items are not available on the target. Not sure if that is the reason.

For example, the package contains some media items and a page item. The page item has few renderings.
This installation failed. I find that, one of the renderings of the page item was referring to a datasource that is not available in the target.
And the result was -
The page was installed, the media images were created but had no images.

When the package has many items, it becomes very difficult to find out where the problem is.

**Troubleshooting**

I created a package for an item from my local instance. Then deleted this item & also its template.
Now I installed the package & installs fine!!!
[Yes, the item is created but on selection it will give an error as its template is not available. This is fine & expected].

I also tried installing this package programmatically, in my local instance.

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
  using (new SyncOperationContext())
    {
      InstallMode installMode = InstallMode.Merge;
      MergeMode mergemode = MergeMode.Append;
      IProcessingContext context = new SimpleProcessingContext();
      IItemInstallerEvents itemEvents = new DefaultItemInstallerEvents(new BehaviourOptions(installMode, mergemode));
      context.AddAspect(itemEvents);
      IFileInstallerEvents fileevents = new DefaultFileInstallerEvents(true);
      context.AddAspect(fileevents);
      Installer installer = new Installer();
      installer.InstallPackage(Sitecore.MainUtil.MapPath(selectedPackagePath), context);
    }
}
```

It's the same thing as above - Installs fine even when template is not available. No errors.

1. What could be the reasons that package installation failed for unavailable items in Azure.
2. I wish the Sitecore installation dialog was more insightful on failure. Is there way where we can check why an installation failed (as I could see nothing in logs).
3. In the above code, is there a way to check the log in case of a failure.

Comment: Is this a very long way of asking, "how do I find my logs in Azure?".  Because your wishes for functionality are unlikely to be resolved by anyone here.

Comment: @MarkCassidy Is there a way to get the status in the code (if not try catch)

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing in the logs? Are you checking in the right place for logs on Azure, you would need to be looking at Application Insights

Comment: @RichardSeal Yes I know the location because I check for logs for other issues. Unfortunatelt no logs about Sitecore Installation failure. Will they be at a different place?